# Когда и кем создается PSP (Program Segment Prefix)?

Tags: ассемблер, exe

Когда и кем (программа) создается PSP? Посмотрел книгу Финогенова, там написано, что создается "системой", но данная формулировка ничего не прояснила. И еще вопрос касаемо наличия этого самого PSP в файлах СОМ и ЕХЕ. PSP создается после загрузки в память или в файле ЕХЕ все-таки он есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@azaznioo](/users/31557/azaznioo)](/users/31557/azaznioo), буквально как написано у Финогенова - блок PSP создается операционной системой DOS при загрузке исполняемого файла в память - для этого на ассемблере при создании COM файла и выполняется команда org 100h - чтобы система эти 100h (256) байт заполнила PSP, а дальше уже загрузилась сама программа.

Касательно наличия этого блока в EXE - он создается, но находится не непосредственно перед кодом/данными программы, а совершенно в другом месте. Адрес его сегмента при запуске программы лежит в ds, а смещение можно получить с помощью [функции 62h прерывания 21h](http://www.htl-steyr.ac.at/~morg/pcinfo/hardware/interrupts/inte8fjk.htm), результат будет находиться в регистре bx.

[Статья на Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Segment_Prefix).

Answer (score 0):

Предыдущий ответ немного неверный.

Для EXE программ PSP находится где то до данных и кода. Да, при запуске программы его сегмент находится в регистре DS. Когда выполняется стартовый код, обычно значение этого регистра DS изменяется на сегмент данных (или DGROUP) и потом его можно узнать вызвав функцию DOS 51h или 62h, которая вернет сегмент PSP в регистре BX. А смещение равно 0. Иными словами:

```
; получаем сегмент PSP
mov ah,51h  ; 62h тоже самое
int 21h
; адрес нашего PSP = BX:0
```